# Selecting block with a mouse when line numbering is enabled

Tags: mouse

How can I select a block with a mouse when line numbering is enabled.
The selection includes the line numbering.
Is there a way to exclude the line numbering from mouse selection ?

Clarification:
The questions if for VIM, not GVIM

Comment: You're not using GVim, right? In GVim I just tried this and the numbers are not selected.

Comment: nope. using vim in a virtual terminal

Comment: `:set mouse=a` should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

OK. So this does not use the mouse.
But that's the whole point of vim (not needing to use the mouse).

You can use the vim normal copy command (which will not select the line numbers). To get it into the system clipboard just use the buffer `*`

```
"*<Normal Yank Command>
```

You have now yanked the text you want into the system clipboard and it can be pasted as normal. The Yank command you use can be any normal vim yank command.